# How to create Laravel Mode and database table without migration?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-5

How to create Laravel Model and database table without migration?

Comment: What do you mean by Laravel Mode?

Comment: sorry, I mean laravel model.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do migration you can directly create database in server like XAMPP or WAMP. And for Model you can create a file and gave it `namespace App;` and create a class. and use that model with `use App\classname;`

Hope it will be useful..